# how i can send and verify parameters from server using volley?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I try to send some parameters to the server to verify. but it doesn't include parameters in URL, I also debug and check the value of my URL but parameters are not there. so how I can do it,
the full URL is look like this "http://38.143.223.234/~wajih/foodaway/api/userlogin.php?email=a%40&device_type=Android&password=123456&device_id=af44077c-e8ec-4b0b-aadb-e322997af8de" 
if I just include all values that I am sending to the server in url then it works well. but I want to send it through parameters method

public void login(){

```
   String url = "http://38.143.223.234/~wajih/foodaway/api/userlogin.php?";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d( "response", response );
                    try {
                        //Boolean error =jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                        //values[0] = values[0].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("1"))
                        {
                            //activity.initializeOneSignal();
                            String user_response = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user_detail").toString();
                            manager.setLoginDetails(user_response);
                            OneSignal.setSubscription(true);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("0"))
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                    jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                     else {
                        // Error didn't get any response from server
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            getWindow().clearFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE );
            if (networkResponse != null) {

                Log.e( "Status code", String.valueOf( networkResponse.statusCode ) );
                Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, String.valueOf( networkResponse.statusCode ),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, error.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }

        }
    }){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<>();
            MyData.put("email", userEmail);
            MyData.put("device_type","Android");
            MyData.put("password", userPassword);
            MyData.put("device_id",deviceId);
            return MyData;
        }
    };

    int socketTimeout = 0;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy( socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT );

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy( policy );
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue( stringRequest);

}
```

Comment: can you please try get method instead of post

Comment: if you want to send parameter through parameter use Get instead Post

Comment: I try GET method as well but the same issue